Whose portrait was in the house in "Cinderella" (1950)?
Whose portrait was in the house in Cinderella (Disney, 1950)?
The portrait I'm referring to:


This really looks like a Modigliani

I'm not fond of this kind of questions, because being set dressing, there is no immediate reason to assume it would be someone in particular, but AFAIK this does (or perhaps should) not fall under the identification closure reason (a "who is this character" question should be a legitimate question on a movie appreciation site). VTLO.

Other portraits in the movie: https://i.sstatic.net/oJc6u5dA.png

Logically, it can only be Cinderella's biological mother. The portrait is of an adult female, who does not resemble any of the living characters that we see in the film.
The house in question belonged to Cinderella's parents, prior to her father's remarriage. Her father would certainly have kept a portrait of his late wife.
As to why Lady Tremaine has not removed the portrait: we can speculate that she did not know who it depicted. Cinderella is smart enough to know that if the identity were known, the picture would be removed. So perhaps it is her little secret.
In support of this theory: the original story opens with Cinderella mourning her mother's death, and the ballet depicts this by having her gaze at her portrait.

well, I suppose before the remake, her mother was a brunette...
